# How to deploy a self signed certificate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, https

I was asked to make our ASP.net mvc3 application https enabled.

So I created a self signed certificate using IIS7 and deployed the same in IIS7
But while taking the https site in webbrowser it says that the certificate cannot be trusted

After googling I understood that manually the client has to add the certificate to trusted site.

The problem is that I need to deploy this application to client's (IIS7).

So what is the correct procedure? 
Does asking the client to manually add the certificate create a bad impression?
Is there any other option by which the certificate can be added to trusted list?

I am very new to this https...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an internal application, then requiring clients to install your certificate is reasonable, as long as you can enforce clients to follow correct procedure about how to obtain and validate your root certificate (otherwise the security of your SSL is a sham).

> Is there any other option by which the certificate can be added to trusted list?

No, but you can purchase an SSL certificate from one of the many certificate providers (i.e. not self signed certificate). These certificate providers have their root certificate included by browser vendors.

For public facing sites, purchasing an SSL certificate is really the only viable option.

Comment: Ok. but I have the impression that the certificate is some how installed by browser. For eg: if i take a banking site they may be using a root CA which is not installed manually by user. How the procedure happens in this scenario

Comment: @Robert_Junior: your browser ships with a list of preinstalled root certificates from popular public CAs like Thawte or Verisign; that's why any certificates generated by these CAs doesn't require you to install their root certificate into the browser. Does this help?